# Protocols and composition on Swift

Tags: swift, protocols, composition

I am trying to learn more about protocols and got stuck without understanding what is going on on the following piece of code. Mostly seeking some light and direction for good articles and pieces of explanation basically.

In one of the examples from Apple's Library protocols are doing a bit more than making sure the classes conform to it.

They are allowing objects from one class to access methods within other classes without using the traditional class inheritance definition.

This line of code  `let generator: RandomNumberGenerator` on the Dice class is allowing the `var d6` that is of type `Dice` to access a function `func random() -> Double` that is outside of `Dice` scope and inside `LinearCongruentialGenerator` scope and is using the `RandomNumberGenerator` to make this bridge.

Also allowing to do the following call `d6.generator.random()` when again `.ramdom()` is not on `Dices` scope.

```
protocol RandomNumberGenerator {
    func random() -> Double
}

class LinearCongruentialGenerator: RandomNumberGenerator {
    var lastRandom = 42.0
    let m = 139968.0
    let a = 3877.0
    let c = 29573.0

    func random() -> Double {
        lastRandom = ((lastRandom * a + c) % m)
        return lastRandom/m
    }
}

class Dice {
    let sides: Int
    let generator: RandomNumberGenerator

    init(sides: Int, generator: RandomNumberGenerator) {

        println(generator.random())

        self.sides = sides
        self.generator = generator
    }

    func roll() -> Int {
        return Int(generator.random() * Double(sides)) + 1
    }
}

var d6 = Dice(sides: 6, generator: LinearCongruentialGenerator())
```

***Update to question***

Thanks for the answers! By doing some research I think I just touched composition. So I wrote the code bellow to exemplify composition a bit better, without using protocols or delegates. Just pure composition. Please let me know if I got it right as it may help other people trying to understand composition.

```
class A {

    var a1: String

    init (valueToA: String){
        self.a1 = valueToA
    }

    func aFunc1() -> A {
        return self
    }
}


class B {

    var b1: A

    init (valueToB: A ) {
        self.b1 = valueToB
    }

    func bFunc1(){
        println("I am bFunc and I am calling aFunc \(b1.aFunc1())")
    }

}

var myA = A(valueToA: "Initiated myA with this string")
//myA.aFunc1()

var myB = B(valueToB: myA)
myB.b1 = A(valueToA: "a value to B")
myB.b1.aFunc1()
```

> The same code but now with protocols

```
protocol myProtocol {
    func protocolFunc(value: String) -> String
}

class A: myProtocol {

    var a1: String

    init (valueToA: String){
        self.a1 = valueToA
    }

    func aFunc1() -> A {
        return self
    }

    func protocolFunc(value: String) -> String {
        return value
    }

}

class B {

    var b1: A
    var b2: myProtocol

    init (valueToB1: A, valueToB2: myProtocol ) {
        self.b1 = valueToB1
        self.b2 = valueToB2
    }

    func bFunc1(){
        println("I am bFunc and I am calling aFunc \(b1.aFunc1())")
    }

    func callProtocolFuncOnA (value: String) {
        b1.protocolFunc(value)
    }

}

var myA1 = A(valueToA: "my A 1 created")
var myA2 = A(valueToA: "my A 2 created")


var myB = B(valueToB1: myA1, valueToB2: A(valueToA: "my A 3 created"))

myB.callProtocolFuncOnA("calling other function")
```

Comment: I think I can't explain that as good as other will do, so I will only post a comment to your question. Protocols can be used to access an instance of some type with some kind of abstraction. It is like you are creating an Instance of `LinearCongruentialGenerator` and then downcast it to `RandomNumberGenerator` so only that part of your implementation is visible to you, which the protocol is providing. It's like telling the compiler to look at your instance with only one eye. ... `let generator: RandomNumberGenerator` can take any instance of any type which conforms to `RandomNumberGenerator`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I think I got the concept of composition, but still trying to get my head around composition done trough protocols as protocols do no implement anything so not so sure how are protocols able to direct the composition to an specific object or method. I will do some more research around it.

Comment: If you are reading the pre-release book then you will also learn that in Swift 2.0 protocols can provide `default implementation`, which is really great and like Christmas for us programmers. :)

Comment: Think about the protocol from your example as an interface. If your type conforms to a protocol and you downscale an instance to that protocol, the only thing you then will see is like an interface with only the functions/methods/inits, which the protocol forced you to implement inside your type. `protocol A { func foo() }` `protocol B { func boo() }` `class C: A, B { func foo() { // nop } func boo() { // nop } }` `let instance: A = C()` `instance.foo() // boo() is not available because C is downscaled to protocol A` ... This is a short example what you could do with a protocol.

Comment: Thanks mate! That helped!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @DevAndArtist says in his comment it allows encapsulation (abstraction) when  a type of `RandomNumberGenerator` is passed in the initializer of the `Dice` class and so only that part of your implementation is visible to you.

In my humble opinion it could be better if the constant `generator` was not visible outside the `Dice` class scope as you say in your question, for example making his access modifier `private`, but remember that in your example all is set in the same swift file and this implies that the `private` access modifier isn't like the other programming languages like C#, Java, etc.

Even doing `private` you can access `d6.generator.random()` in your call because it exist in the same Swift file, the only way you can hide the property if you create a new Swift file for the `Dice` class and then this call when the property is private of course :

```
var d6 = Dice(sides: 6, generator: LinearCongruentialGenerator())
println(d6.generator.random())
```

gave you the following error:

```
'Dice' does not have a member named 'generator'
```

And you can hide the property outside of its scope. It's only a point of view.

I hope this help you.

Comment: is encapsulation (abstraction) the same as composition?

Comment: It's not exactly the same concept, Encapsulation is something like hiding unnecessary data and composition is a special case of inheritance

Comment: Victor, I think this is also helping me to understand what delegation is.  

Can I say that the concept of delegation "just happens" when you simply arrange your code on a way where objects/methods asks other object/method to perform some tasks? If that is true, delegation is a very subtle thing… happens all the time in object oriented programming. 

So basically when `func A1` that is inside `Class A` asked `func B` that is outside of `Class A` scope to perform some work the `Class A` is delegating some of it’s tasks to `func B`. In a very simplistic way, this is delegation right?

Comment: With that in mind, delegation can happen in a extremely basic way (that i described above) or can happen in a very complex way by making use of protocols, inheritance, composition, etc…

Other thing I could say is: more delegation you use, bigger are the chances your code is better prepared for scalability and better flexibility it will have?